# Is a quad in a triangular shape still bad for topology?

Tags: modeling, topology

I am trying to make an anime style model with a good topology but I keep running into quads (faces with 4 vertices). If I tried to make it square it would really mess up the model. The model is supposed to be for animations. I have the quads on the cheeks of the mesh and I do plan on rigging the face.

Comment: If it has 4 vertices it's not a triangle ;) Also good topology is generally considered to be a quad based model (polygons with 4 sides) so you should be ok

Comment: It depends on what's around it. What does the edge flow look like? How is the geometry going to deform? These are questions to ask yourself when considering your topology. It's still possible to have all-quad bad topology (like diamond quads on an edge), and also possible to have tris in your mesh and have it be OK if they're in an area that won't deform much.

Comment: Quads aren't always good for so-called "good topology". What's the purpose of your model? Are the vertices on the same plane (keyword: deformation)? Do the loopcuts look good?

Comment: A guest, it would be of extreme benefit to me if you might post screenshots of your model, and upload a copy of your ~.blend file to <http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good trig or quad topology depends on what you intend to use it for.
If you want to use blender modeling function (such as subsurf, snooth and other deformations) it is better to use quad since trig can make ugly/buggy result.

Some publications say trig can be usefull in animation or game but it depend what software you use. But usually quad is  better.